# Why is pip on version 3 and python -V on python 2.7

Tags: python, pip

```
~$ export PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin/python"
:~$ pip --version
pip 21.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip (python 3.6)
~$ python -V
Python 2.7.17
```

Why is pip on python3? I want pip to be on python2.

I have tried adding path of python2 to the PATH variable but it didn't help.
Please help me understand why this happened and how can I change pip to python2.7 for the system

Comment: Possibly you need to use `/usr/bin` upfront: `/usr/bin/:$PATH`, bwz. use directories for $PATH.

Comment: If you do `python -m pip --version`, you are sure you are going to use the pip linked with the python version